# Probability density of a hyperplane for a Gaussian distribution

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, integration, gaussian, multivariable-calculus

I have a vector $\mathbf{x}$ with a multivariate Gaussian distribution
$$P[\textbf{x}\in S]
=\int_{\textbf{x}\in S}
\det(2\pi H^{-1})^{-1/2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2} \textbf{x}^T H\textbf{x}) \, d\textbf{x}$$How can I compute probability densities within the hyperplane $\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{g}=C$ using the standard Lebesgue measure? ${}$

The closest question & answer I have found on this site was for a particular instance of Gaussian and hyperplane [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/381215/102071).

Comment: I cannot attach any meaning to "the probability density of the hyperplane $\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{g}=C$ using the standard Lebesgue measure" and also to "the probability density of a one-dimensional gaussian involving $\textbf{x}^*$".

Comment: The standard answer is to define 
$$P[\textbf{x}\in S|f(\textbf{x})=C]=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\frac
{P[\textbf{x}\in S \cap f^{-1}([C-\epsilon,C+\epsilon])}
{P[\textbf{x}\in f^{-1}([C-\epsilon,C+\epsilon])}$$
where in this case we use $f(\textbf{x})=
\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{g}$. The question is then how to transform this expression into a similar expression without a limit.

Comment: Make a linear change of variables which makes the Gaussian standard, then an orthogonal change of variables which makes your plane orthogonal to a basic vector.

Comment: @MattF Although your parsing of my (poorly written) question makes a lot of sense, my question was different. Using your notation, what I wanted was probably simpler, just $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{P[\textbf{x}\in f^{-1}([C-\epsilon, C+\epsilon])}{\epsilon}$, where $f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{g}$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis ' answer is good and valuable, so I'm inclined to just keep the question as edited and accept the answer. Does this sound good? If my question doesn't have a 2-line answer for this comment section (which it very well might) should I just create a new question here or on the non-professional math exchange? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I was able to find the answer to my simple question on the stats stack exchange [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375068/distribution-of-the-dot-product-of-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-and-a). It was better to not frame it with hyper-planes and instead see it as the result of taking the dot product of a multivariate gaussian with a fixed vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$First, one should not denote a random vector in $\R^n$ (which is not actually a vector in $\R^n$ but a function with values in $\R^n$) and a true, non-random vector in $\R^n$ by the same symbol, such as $\mathbf x$.

Accordingly, let $X\sim N(0,S)$, where $S:=H^{-1}$. Let $c:=C$ and $g:=\mathbf g\ne0$. We want to find the conditional density of $X$ given $X^\top g=c$; as usual, we identify $\R^n$ with the set $\R^{n\times1}$ of all $n\times1$ real matrices. Without loss of generality,
$g$ is a unit vector; otherwise, replace $g$ and $c$ by $g/|g|$ and $c/|g|$, respectively, where $|g|$ is the Euclidean norm of $g$. Let
$g_1,\dots,g_n$
be any orthonormal vectors in $\R^n$ such as $g_n=g$.

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be the coordinates of the random vector $X$ in the orthonormal basis $(g_1,\dots,g_n)$, so that $Y_k=g_k^\top X$ and $X=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_kg_k$. Let $Y:=[Y_1,\dots,Y_n]^\top$, so that
$Y=G^\top X$ and $X=GY$, where $G:=[g_1,\dots,g_n]$, the $n\times n$ matrix with columns $g_1,\dots,g_n$. The covariance matrix of $Y$ is
\begin{equation}
    EYY^\top=G^\top SG=:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \Si_{11}&\Si_{12} \\ 
    \Si_{21}&\Si_{22} 
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $\Si_{12}$ is the $(n-1)\times1$ matrix that is the covariance matrix of $[Y_1,\dots,Y_{n-1}]^\top$ and $Y_n$. Also, $Y\sim N(0,G^\top SG)$.
So, the [conditional pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) of $[Y_1,\dots,Y_{n-1}]^\top$ given $Y_n=c$ is the pdf, say $p_c$, of the $(n-1)$-dimensional normal distribution
\begin{equation}
    N(\Si_{12}\Si_{22}^{-1}c,\Si_{11}-\Si_{12}\Si_{22}^{-1}\Si_{21}).
\end{equation}

This conditional pdf, $p_c$, can be regarded as the desired conditional density of $X$ given $X^\top g=c$. Indeed, $p_c$ can be used as follows: for any (say) nonnegative Borel function $f\colon\R^n\to\R$,
\begin{equation}
    E(f(X)|X^\top g=c)=E(f(GY)|Y_n=c) \\ 
    =\int_{\R^{n-1}}f(G[y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},c]^\top)p_c(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})\,
    dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}. 
\end{equation}
In particular, for any Borel subset $B$ of $\R^n$,
\begin{equation}
    P(X\in B|X^\top g=c)=P(GY\in B|Y_n=c) \\ 
    =\int_{\R^{n-1}}1(G[y_1,\dots,y_{n-1},c]^\top\in B)p_c(y_1,\dots,y_{n-1})\,
    dy_1\cdots dy_{n-1}. 
\end{equation}